# Prism event aggregator collection

Tags: wpf, prism

For a utility I am looking to write, I would like to be able to access the dictionary of events that are maintained by the event aggregator in Prism... the only public method/property seems to be "GetEvent". is it possible to get at the dictionary of events?

Thanks
harold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with the out of the box implementation. A possible solution to this would be to possibly subclass either EventBase or WPFPresentationEvent.

Take a look at this [implementation](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/11/adding-store-and-forward-support-to-the-prism-eventaggregator/) for a bit of inspiration..

Comment: ok thanks very much! thought this might have to be the case.. that link was helpful.